# Only show theme option if it option exists

Tags: options

I have a slideshow in a custom theme I am developing and I am using the UpThemes Framework, what I want to know is, is there a way and image will only display if it has been defined?

For example, at the moment the max. number of images in the slideshow is 6, but if only 5 are uploaded the "alt" attribute displays for the 6th

For those unfamiliar with the framework, this is the PHP tag I am using

```
<?php echo $up_options->slideshow6; ?>
```

I have done this with custom fields in the past but I can't for the life of me figure out how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to output based on the option being *defined*, then use `isset()`. e.g. this:

```
<?php echo $up_options->slideshow6; ?>
```

...becomes this:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $up_options->slideshow6 ) ) {
    echo $up_options->slideshow6;
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

> How would I get the following to appear only if "slideshow6" was defined `<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $up_options->slideshow1; ?>" alt="#"/></a>`

I would go with:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $up_options->slideshow6 ) ) {
    echo '<a href="#"><img src="' . $up_options->slideshow1 . '" alt="#"/></a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like from the description that it *is* defined, but points to a non-existent image (i.e. a HTML `<img />` string with a blank `src`)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I assume that `$up_options->slideshow6` is the *image SRC* itself?

Comment: `$up_options->slideshow6` is the src, yes

Comment: Chip's code worked a treat, although I forgot to include the full line of code earlier. How would I get the following to appear only if "slideshow6" was defined `<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $up_options->slideshow1; ?>" alt="#"/></a>`

Comment: @ChipBennett My assumption was based on the code provided - Dean Elliot has enlightened the situation ;)

Comment: @DeanElliott Just replace Chip's echo statement with `echo "<a href='#'><img src='{$up_options->slideshow6}' alt='' /></a>";`